# Remove specific CSS rule or selector on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i remove a specific CSS Selector or rule from an HTML with jquery or javascript?

For example i use Telerik ASP Ajax controls and i want to remove the predefined loaded css rule for a theme from their cdn, completely from the control.

When the telerik control (in this example the radwindow) is loading it's css file from the cdn it contains for example the following css

```
.rwTopLeft
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 168, 0); 
}
```

I want to remove that css rule from the page via javascript or remove the specific class definition for the control.

Comment: Please add code which shows what you've tried yet.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList, http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: `$(function(){
        $('.yourspecific class').removeClass('yourspecific class');
    });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this to remove a class:

```
 $("#yourId").removeClass('yourclass');
```

But to remove a css rule you have to set it to null, same examples here:

```
 $("#yourId").css('border','none');
 $("#yourId").css('width','auto');
```

Or

```
 $("#yourId").css('border','');
 $("#yourId").css('width','');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#yourId").removeClass('yourclass');
```

It needs jQuery.